# Как создать виртуальный столбец в SQLiteStudio?

Tags: sqlite

Как создать виртуальный столбец именно в SQLiteStudio? Неужели только полностью SQL запросом, создав таблицу заново?

Comment: Виртуальный столбец - это generated column, что ли? тогда обычным ALTER TABLE.

Comment: Согласно документации SQLite generated column типа STORAGE не может быть создан ALTER TABLE, только типа VIRTUAL, но он меняется при чтении. А мне нужно при записи чтобы данные менялись.

Comment: Давайте будем более предметными. Добавьте в текст вопроса текущий CREATE TABLE и требуемый.